# Jubula Automated Function Testing?

Tags: testing, jubula

I am new to Jubula.Struggling hard to understand the flow of Jubula.I have installed the standalone application of Jubula(Version:8) in windows.I am finding tutorials to test java RCP application but I need to test a Website.Is it possible to test web sites using Jubula?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a tutorial for testing a website at the moment. However, once you've understood how tests are created in general, the steps are the same for testing a web application.

The one main difference is that the object mapping is performed via click instead of via key combination. Relevant documentation is here and in the reset of the user manual and in the reference manual:

- http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jubula.client.ua.help/content/html/userManual/toolkit/webAUT/webaut.html?cp=45_3_5

I'm assuming that you've found the "cheat sheets", which take you through the steps and workflows of working with Jubula? If not, they are under "Help/Cheat Sheets" in the application.

The Jubula forum is also a good place to ask questions:
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=208